# PHP Core Error – yii\base\ErrorException Directive 'register_long_arrays' is no longer available in PHP

Tags: php, yii2

**I know this question already exist in the SO,But**

I use shared hosting for my server and their service is exceptionally bad. So I want to know,is there anyway to fix this issue from the application side.

Or removing the ''register_long_arrays'' reference from php.ini is the only way to get rid of this error?

**Screenshot**
http://manfredinfotech.com/projects/sc/sc.png

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to legacy code in their `php.ini` file.
If you are using .htaccess files, you can try placing the flag `php_flag register_long_arrays Off` in the root `.htaccess` file.

The [`register_long_arrays`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays) directive has been deprecated since PHP 5.3 and removed since PHP 5.4, and Yii2 is supported for PHP >= 5.4
So if you're running a PHP 5.3 server, you're in trouble!

Comment: I have already tried it. But no success! If the directive is deprecated we can not set it to Off,but has to remove the complete reference from php.ini

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running? And what's the hosting?

Comment: Both are different. Development version is 5.6 and server version 5.4

Comment: Then is the problem I mentioned. It's because the server has set that option in their `php.ini` file. Some hostings allow to override some of their `php.ini` options, placing a `php.ini` file in the root of your home folder. Maybe you can try that!

Comment: I tried that too. I tried both php.ini and .user.ini

Comment: Then, you have ran out of choices I believe. Do you need hosting recommendations? :P